# Idiomatic way to do conditional list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I just started learning Haskell and I can't seem to find a good solution to create a list conditionally.

Basically, what I want is to do list comprehension with an `if/else` but without the `else` part. I am certain this is possible, I guess I am just using the wrong keywords on my googling quest.

A very stupid example in Python which I want to Haskellize:

```py
[x for x in range(11) if x > 5]
```

In Haskell, as far as I understand we cannot omit `else` blocks like I did in the Python example. How should I do something like this? Does something like *nothing* exists which I can add to the `else`-block in list comprehension, like so:

```hs
[if x > 5 then x else Nothing | x <- [0..10]]
```

I actually came across *Nothing* in Haskell, though I haven't figure it out yet. It certainly doesn't seem to do what I hoped. Basically I don't want an `else` in my list comprehension, but if it's a necessary evil I want to insert nothing in the `else` block.

I can think of a bunch of hacks to get similar functionality very inefficiently:

- `filter` the list after creating it, e.g. `filter (>5) [0..10]`
- create a list of lists using list comprehension, for which I can create an empty list in the else block and then `concat` them, e.g. `concat [if x > 5 then [x] else [] | x <- [0..10]]`

These ideas all seem *really* ugly, though.

<sub>Ofcourse in practice I don't want to create conditional lists with such trivial conditions.</sub>

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the filter approach tbh. Written in one line it seems perfectly elegant. Just maybe not very Pythonic.

Comment: @jwg I'm not fully aware of the implications of Haskell's laziness yet so maybe I don't give that approach enough credit. I *assume* that the filter approach first creates the full list and then subsequently filters it. This is something I want to avoid.

Comment: `filter` does not cause the list passed to it to be evaluated fully; see http://pastebin.com/D05bc4TN for a demonstration.

Comment: @ErikAllik thanks. I guess that solves my problem efficiently as well then.

Comment: definitely, although I'd say for data you define statically (as opposed to compose dynamically at runtime), list comprehensions are nicer from a readability and expressiveness point of view.

Comment: @ErikAllik yes, I definitely agree wrt readability. It's going to take a while to wrap my head around Haskell programming (coming from C++). I feel like Alice in Wonderland right now.

Comment: I feel that I started understanding, and appreciating the potential of, Haskell only when I switched to Scala, having been mainly a Python guy for the past 4-5 years or so before that. So whereas this is not an attempt to advertise Scala over Haskell, what I'm saying is that sometimes less pure and more mixed languages (both in terms of semantics and syntax) make it easier to connect mathematical ideas to real life solutions (assuming they are powerful enough compared to Haskell), which in turn builds intuition faster, unless mathematics is in your blood.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this:

```
Prelude> [x | x <- [0..10], x > 5]
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

In Haskell list comprehensions, the "source" expression and all the filters/ifs are "siblings", i.e. there's not much syntactic distinction between them, unlike in Python. So

```
<expr1> for <source_expr> if <cond_expr>
```

is just this in Haskell:

```
[<expr1> | <source_expr>, <cond_expr>, ...]
```

(`source_expr` being `x in range(0, 10)` in Python or `x <- [0..9]` in Haskell)

and you can have as many "source" and "filter" expressions in a Haskell list comprehension as you like.

This also means that you can write stuff in a style more similar to the mathematical notation; consider:

```
{ x : x ∈ [0, 10), x > 5 }
```

and see how the Haskell version is almost the same, compared to the Python one, which looks much more procedural/imperative.

---

This also works out trivially without any need for additional syntax/constructs with **multiple "source" expressions**:

```
Prelude> [(x, y) | x <- [0..10], y <- [10..20], y - x < 5]
[(6,10),(7,10),(7,11),(8,10),(8,11),(8,12),(9,10),(9,11),(9,12),(9,13),(10,10),(10,11),(10,12),(10,13),(10,14)]
```

In Python you would have to have what looks like a nested list comprehension, however Haskell still just sticks to the mathematical approach/notation.

Answer (score 5):

What Python calls `if` doesn't exist as such in Haskell. For "if without else" to make sense at all you need a notion of what "doing nothing" even means – normally, the very idea doesn't make sense in a functional language because functions are all about *I guarantee you, for any argument you give me I'll return a useful answer*. You can't just say, "nah, don't feel like returning anything"... **unless** no-result happens to be a value of the return type. That is in fact given for lists, which is the only reason it's useful to think about filtering in the first place.

More generally, "nothingness" is captured by a particular kind of monad: [the `MonadPlus` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t%3aMonadPlus). In fact, the simplest instance is the `Nothing` constructor you've already stumbled on:

> Prelude Control.Monad> mzero :: Maybe Int
>   Nothing

You see it has `Maybe` in its type, i.e. we make it explicit that *it's not guaranteed there will be a result*!

Selecting between "yield something, or not" is not called `if` in Haskell, but `guard`. In monadic writing, your comprehension looks thus:

```
yourList = do
   x <- [0..11]
   guard (x > 5)
   return x
```

And indeed the list comprehension `[ x | x <- [0..11], x>5 ]` is basically syntactic sugar for that.

`guard` is a bit weird if you don't understand monads. There's another function you'll also see often which does something very similar (albeit in quite a different way), `when`, this one is normally used for the "execute-or-don't–if" in imperative languages.

Comment: Thanks for this intuitive explanation. I understood the reasoning behind the no-if-without-else policy in Haskell but there are indeed some situations where it *does* make sense. Now it's time for me to start reading about guards.

Comment: As I said, `guard` is really a bit confusing and not used very often. Really, the idiomatic way is to either use `filter` (or something analogous), or list comprehensions. And the imperative `if` is modelled not by `guard` but by `when`, so perhaps better read up on that. — As for [_guards_](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards): those are again something different, essentially just a nicer way to write a long `if-then-elseif-else...`. They are _not_ implemented with `guard` and have nothing to do with monads.